# Graphql-Ruby: Creating interfaces that objects can inherit fields from

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, graphql, graphql-ruby

```
    module Types::ProgramType
        include Types::BaseInterface
    
        description "Objects which inherit from Program"
        graphql_name "Program"
        orphan_types Types::SomeProgramType, Types::AnotherProgramType, Types::ThirdProgramType
    
        field :id, ID, null: false
        field :type, Integer, null: false
        field :name, String, null: false

    definition_methods do
      def self.resolve_type(object, _context)
        case object.class
        when SomeProgram then SomeProgramType
        when AnotherProgram then AnotherProgramType
        when ThirdProgram then ThirdProgramType
        else
          raise "Unknown program type"
        end
      end
    end
    end
    
    module Types
      class SomeProgramType < Types::BaseObject
        implements Types:ProgramType
    
        field :description, String, null: false
      end
    end
```

I also added queries for SomeProgram types in the query_type file. I was under the impression that adding "implement " to the object types, would allow them to inherit the fields from the interface (per this link: https://graphql-ruby.org/type_definitions/interfaces) and I would be able to query like this:

```
    query {
            someProgram(id: 1) {
               name
               type
               description
            }
}
```

But I am getting errors in graphiql, like "Field 'name' doesn't exist on type 'SomeProgram'". What am I missing?

Update:

My QueryType class:

```
class QueryType < Types::BaseObject
    # Add `node(id: ID!) and `nodes(ids: [ID!]!)`
    include GraphQL::Types::Relay::HasNodeField
    include GraphQL::Types::Relay::HasNodesField

    field :some_programs, [SomeProgramType], null: false,
      description: "all some programs"

    def some_programs
      SomeProgram.all
    end

    field :some_program, SomeProgramType, null: false do
      argument :id, ID, required: true
    end

    def some_program(id:)
      SomeProgram.find(id)
    end
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out the issue. I had put `implements Types:SomeProgram` instead of `implements Types::SomeProgram`. I was missing a colon.

Answer (score 1):

Can you also share how you expose `someProgram` in your query type?

You can also debug this by looking into the schema if you are using GraphiQL app. You can see the return type of `someProgram` which should be type of `ProgramType`.

You can also update your query to include `__typename` so maybe start with

```
query {
   someProgram(id: 1) {
       __typename
   }
}
```

First to see what is the return type and if it's being properly handled in the `resolve_type`

Comment: I added the QueryType above. I tried running your query with typename and now I I'm getting a different error which is much more helpful though still very confusing. "Failed to implement Query.somePrograms, tried:\n\n          - `Types::QueryType#some_programs`, which did not exist\n          - `NilClass#some_programs`, which did not exist\n          - Looking up hash key `:some_programs` or `\"some_programs\"` on ``, but it wasn't a Hash"

Comment: Messed around with things too much. Fixed it but still can't inherit the fields from the ProgramType interface. Now the the results are: {
  "data": {
    "someProgram": {
      "__typename": "SomeProgram"
    }
  }
}

Comment: shouldn't the `__typename` be `SomeProgramType`? i feel like your `resolve_type` is not working as expected. I would put a debug message in `resolve_type` and see where it lands.